# Troubleshooting date changes in Win7

Tags: windows-7, troubleshooting

My PC when booting flashes some white stripes (before anything) 2-3 times and then something related to BIOS comes (in DOS style on black background), then when PC is booted up, changes date either to maximum or minimum possible (the time too). I think there's some problem, what should I do to try to fix it?

And I think that maybe the problem is even bigger  than this and there might be some inner problems too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the symptoms, the first step would be to see if your CMOS battery is depleted.

To do so:

1. Discharge static electricity in your body
2. Locate the CMOS battery on the motherboard
3. Carefully remove the battery
4. Determine appropriate voltage of battery
5. Test voltage of battery using a multimeter or battery tester
6. If the battery is low, dispose appropriately (may be hazardous waste), and replace

Comment: is it common since I bought my PC in 2010 and haven't changed it since then?

Comment: @ADG Great question.  The answer is yes.  If you bought the PC in 2010, it was probably manufactured around 2009.  The battery itself was probably manufactured in 2005-2008 (possibly earlier).  That very rough estimate puts the battery at 7 to 10+ years old, which would mean there is a good chance it can no longer deliver sufficient energy to serve it's function.